# 1 single instance of a patternProperty allowed in JSonSchema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a JsonSchema looking like this

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "definitions": {},
    "id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[0-9]$": {
....
....
....
        }
     }
}
```

What I want this Schema to validate is, if there is a JSON string with 0 or 1 of this patternProperty

So for example

```
{
   "0":{}
}
```

is a right output

```
{
}
```

is also a right output

```
{
   "0":{},
   "1":{}
}
```

would be a wrong output even though the patternProperty matches of both, but there is more than 1 node

Is this somehow possible with JSonSchema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [maxProperties](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.15) and [minProperties](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.16).
If you want exactly one property you can do this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "patternProperties": {
    "[a-z]": {}
  },
  "maxProperties": 1,
  "minProperties": 1
}
```